# Which part of the computer has to be replaced to add UEFI support?

Tags: motherboard, uefi

I have recently acquired a computer that does not support booting into UEFI mode. However, I don't know which component of the computer to replace such that UEFI booting is supported. From what I can tell, UEFI is a replacement for BIOS, and thus it must be the motherboard. If I replace my computer's motherboard with a newer one, will this system then support booting into UEFI?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. BIOS/UEFI is MB's option, so that's the component you're wanting to replace.

Comment: Be aware there are other, possibly significant, implications of replacing a motherboard... If this is an OEM system (Dell, HP, etc) with a OEM Windows license, the license will no longer be valid if you replace the motherboard and you will need to reinstall the operating system (you can't just switch from BIOS/Legacy to UEFI on the fly) possibly meaning you need to purchase a Windows license. Then there is also the possibility of expansion card problems (not enough PCI slots or the graphics card is AGP but the motherboad has PCI-E, etc)